# I found out that Firebase didn't work with the ejs file. What about DigitalOcean?

Tags: node.js, firebase, ejs, digital-ocean

I've been using Firebase for a while but I realized this didn't work with an ejs file. If I have only one file which is an ejs file to host on an ACTUAL webpage, would DigitalOcean work with ejs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on how you're trying to use EJS files.

[Firebase Hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting) is a static file host, which means that Firebase's servers don't do anything with the contents of your files. If you're trying to serve EJS files, so that they're rendered in the browser, then Firebase Hosting alone is already fine.

If you want the EJS to be rendered on the server, then that is not possible with just Firebase Hosting. But you can [integrate Firebase Hosting with Cloud Functions or Cloud Run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions), which are essentially managed Node.js environments. And in that case you could run the EJS in Cloud Functions, which is hosted in Firebase Hosting.

For more on this, I highly recommend checking out the [Firebase documentation on use-cases for hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/use-cases).

Note that all of these are probably also quite possible on Digital Ocean. Since you'd be using a VM there, you can essentially do whatever you want. The trade-off is that you'd lose the auto-scaling that Firebase offers there.

Comment: Doesn't Firebase Cloud Functions run "index.js" sitting in "functions" folder? which means it should be a file with "js" extension, not "ejs" extension right?

Comment: I went from https://ejs.co/, which seems to show how to use EJS templates within a regular Node.js script. In there `ejs` is just a node module, and you call out to with something like `ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});` The template string in there can come from a file of course, and that file can be deployed in your `functions` folder.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to Firebase not work with EJS or even DigitalOcean. If you are integrating Firebase in front-end your problem is not back-end related.

Comment: Can you tell me specifically how Firebase can work with an ejs file? According to Firebase documentation and others' answers from other questions, Firebase only has "two ways" to host a website which are 1. hosting index.html directly OR 2. using Cloud Functions to run a JavaScript file sitting in functions folder.

Answer (score 0):

digital ocean works for firebase if you using the front and for that

Comment: Digital Ocean and Firebase are both hosting platforms so I'm not sure what you mean by "digital ocean works for firebase". Are you talking about using both Firebase and Digital Ocean at the same time? that makes no sense to me.